# Finding $P(Y>\theta+1)$ when $X$ has pdf $f(x)=e^{-(x-\theta)}1_{x\ge\theta}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume that the random variable $X$ has the distribution
$f(x; \theta) = e^{−(x − \theta)} , x \ge\theta$,
while $f(x; \theta) = 0$ for $x < \theta$;  $\theta$ denotes a constant parameter.

Let $Y = 2X + 3$. Determine the probability density of the random variable Y. Rain
out the probability that $Y> \theta + 1$.

What I can't figure out is how to solve this, when I know the answer to the last part $Y> \theta + 1$ should be 1.

for the first part, I got that the PDF of $Y$ was $\frac{1}{2}e^{-(y-3)/2 + \theta}$ but cannot get the answer for the second part to add up to $1$.

Comment: It is evident that $Y=2X+3\geq2\theta+3$ almost surely, but that only leads to $Y>\theta+1$ a.s. under the following condition on the parameter: $\theta+1\geq2\theta+3$. Btw, I think the PDF found by you misses a factor $\frac12$.

Comment: Here's a MathJax tutorial for typsetting math on this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: The probability $P(Y>\theta+1)$ equals $1$ only when $\theta+1\le 2\theta+3$, i.e. for $\theta\ge -2$. Otherwise, it is just a function of $\theta$.